# What is the equivalent phrase of the figurative 'red meat' in Chinese?

Tags: translation, mandarin, cantonese, equivalent-phrase

'Red meat' literally means 紅肉 (e.g. beef, lamb) in Chinese, but it is typically used in a figurative sense in political commentaries. For Example: "His outrageous statements are red meat for his supporters"

> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/red+meat
>
> red meat
>
> n.
>
> 1. Meat, such as beef or lamb, that is dark red before being cooked.
> 2. **Language or discourse intended to stir the emotions of a given group, especially by appealing to or reinforcing partisan sentiments.**

I do not believe that Chinese speakers use '紅肉' figuratively like English speakers use 'red meat' in English.

'投其所好的言論' would be my translation of the figurative 'red meat', but I wonder is there a Chinese counterpart of this term.

Comment: I think the idea in English is not that the partisans like "red meat."  It is more about stirring up emotions, especially aggressive emotions.   Offering them "red meat" in this sense is like letting them "smell blood."

Comment: [The OP's interpretation: ]
討好奉承拍馬屁，
阿諛逢迎獻殷勤，
趨奉迎合投其好，
諂媚巴結討歡心。

[The Colin McLarty's interpretation:]
挑動鼓動又煽動，
誘惑蠱惑也煽惑，
引誘哄誘再利誘，
(啊......不然呢？)
策動慫恿並唆使。

Answer (score 1):

I believe the verb 「挑動」, 「煽動」 or 「蛊惑（人心）」 might match the definition "to stir the emotions" in your dictionary, if you need derogatory terms.

「投其所好」 and 「奉承」 are about flattering someone.

Answer (score 0):

well, In Chinese, we don't have special terms have the same mean of 'read meat'.
we use 阿谀逢迎（a formal literary language），while in daily life, we just use 拍马屁. it is the mean of 'offer someone with red meat', but we don't have noun as the mean of 'read meat'